# Dynamically importing an svg in React

Tags: reactjs, svg, webpack, babeljs

I have a dumb component that gets passed down props from a weatherAPI. I want to be able to dynamically change the SVG image depending on what gets sent back from the API. I have installed an npm module `react-svg`: https://github.com/atomic-app/react-svg. This has a dependency of `svg-injector`: https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg-injector which I have also installed. Now, I have imported `react-svg` -> `import ReactSVG from 'react-svg';`. I then implemented it with inside my dumb component:

```
const WeatherReport = ({report}) => {
return (
    <div style={styles.body} className="row">
        <div style={styles.weatherBoxContainer}>
            <div className="col-sm-2 col-md-offset-1" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherCard}>
                <div style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherReport}>
                    <ReactSVG path={'RELATIVE TO DOCUMENT ROOT I'M SERVING FROM'} callback={(svg) => console.log(svg)} />
                    <div className="row" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.temps}>
                        <div className="col-sm-4" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.tempMinMax}>
                            <div>{Math.floor(report.list[0].main.temp_max)}°</div>
                            <div>{Math.floor(report.list[0].main.temp_min)}°</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-8" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.currentTemp}>
                            {Math.floor(report.list[0].main.temp)}°
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                CA
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-2" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherCard}>
                <div style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherReport}>
                    <div className="row" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.temps}>
                        <div className="col-sm-4" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.tempMinMax}>
                            <div>{Math.floor(report.list[1].main.temp_max)}°</div>
                            <div>{Math.floor(report.list[1].main.temp_min)}°</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-8" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.currentTemp}>
                            {Math.floor(report.list[1].main.temp)}°
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                UT
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-2" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherCard}>
                <div style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherReport}>
                    <div className="row" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.temps}>
                        <div className="col-sm-4" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.tempMinMax}>
                            <div>{Math.floor(report.list[2].main.temp_max)}°</div>
                            <div>{Math.floor(report.list[2].main.temp_min)}°</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-8" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.currentTemp}>
                            {Math.floor(report.list[2].main.temp)}°
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                MN
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-2" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherCard}>
                <div style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherReport}>
                    <div className="row" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.temps}>
                        <div className="col-sm-4" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.tempMinMax}>
                            <div>{Math.floor(report.list[3].main.temp_max)}°</div>
                            <div>{Math.floor(report.list[3].main.temp_min)}°</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-8" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.currentTemp}>
                            {Math.floor(report.list[3].main.temp)}°
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                DC
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-2" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherCard}>
                <div style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.weatherReport}>
                    <div className="row" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.temps}>
                        <div className="col-sm-4" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.tempMinMax}>
                            <div>{Math.floor(report.list[4].main.temp_max)}°</div>
                            <div>{Math.floor(report.list[4].main.temp_min)}°</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="col-sm-8" style={styles.weatherBoxContainer.currentTemp}>
                            {Math.floor(report.list[4].main.temp)}°
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                NY
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
);
};

WeatherReport.propTypes = {
report: PropTypes.object
};

export default WeatherReport;
```

Now, ReactSVG's path needs to be relative to the document root you're serving from NOT relative to the js file that contains ReactSVG. Simple enough right? However, I am using babel and everything is being served as JS, into one file. I am quite new to `webpack`, `babel`, `react` and `redux` for that matter... Any suggestions on how I am suppose to hit the path to my `svg` when everything is being compiled into one file?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the output from your build step in webpack is into a `/dist/` folder off your root (for example) you would also want to have a build step to copy any other external files in that folder such as your `svg` file.

```
/dist
|- bundle.js
|- myart.svg
```

Then in your file you can reference the `svg` simply as

```
<ReactSVG path="myart.svg" />
```