# Can't find how to import an svg icon library in React

Tags: reactjs, svg, import, icons, components

I have scouted plenty of Stackoverflow questions or searched for articles. But I can only find npm packages and I do want to avoid using too many packages in my Project. 

**All I ask is for some guidence, articles, blogposts, links, whatever could help me to achieve what I want.**

### What  I want

Is dynamically import 50+ svg icons as components in React; ready to be used. 
The reason is so that when an svg icon is replaced with the name kept the same, it immediately updates all the icon versions in my app.
Extra: if it could be possible to package this to be used in other projects; that would be amazing.

### What I currently do

Beneath is what I'm currently doing; but this is crazy work for 50 icons that might one day be updated.

```
import React from 'react';

const getViewBox = name => {
  switch (name) {
    case 'mouseScroll':
    return '0 0 70 130'
    default:
      return '0 0 50 50';
  }
};

const icons = (name, props) => {
  switch (name) {
    case 'loading':
      return (
        <g>
          <path {...props} d="M25,50C11.2,50,0,38.8,0,25S11.2,0,25,0c0.8,0,1.5,0.7,1.5,1.5S25.8,3,25,3C12.9,3,3,12.9,3,25s9.9,22,22,22
            c12.1,0,22-9.9,22-22c0-0.8,0.7-1.5,1.5-1.5S50,24.2,50,25C50,38.8,38.8,50,25,50z"/>
        </g>
      );
    case 'mouseScroll':
      return (
        <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
          <rect width="70" height="118" x="1.5" y="1.5" stroke="#FFF" stroke-width="5" rx="36"/>
          <circle className="scroll" cx="38.5" cy="33.5" r="6.5" fill="#FFF"/>
        </g>
      );
    default:
      return '';
  }
};

const SVGIcon = ({
  name = '',
  style = {},
  fill = 'currentColor',
  viewBox = '',
  width = '20px',
  className = 'icon icon' + name,
  height = '20px'
}) => (
  <svg
    width={width}
    style={style}
    height={height}
    className={className}
    xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'
    viewBox={viewBox || getViewBox(name)}
    xmlnsXlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'
  >
    {icons(name, { fill })}
  </svg>
);

export default SVGIcon;
```

### What almost helped me

Is the answer by user skylize in this Stackoverflow question: 
[How to import an entire folder of SVG images (or how to load them dynamically) into a React Web App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754739/how-to-import-an-entire-folder-of-svg-images-or-how-to-load-them-dynamically-i/46210355)

But here the svgs are merely filepaths to be used in  tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**svgr**](https://github.com/smooth-code/svgr) you can import your svg's as a component.

If you want to avoid importing the package, and "recreate the wheel" look in the source code of the lib and you will find some good insght.

Look inside this [**repo**](https://github.com/smooth-code/svgr/tree/master/packages/core) the svgr/core for inspiration, code is self documented and easy to understand.

Comment: This looks like what I've been looking for. Thanks a lot!