# Importing SVG in React dynamically

Tags: reactjs, svg

I'm trying to import SVG dynamically in my React Component

So instead of doing import { ReactComponent as LikeIcon } from '../../assets/svg/like.svg' everytime I need an svg I need to pass the name "like" for example to dynamically import it

I found a solution here: [How to dynamically import SVG and render it inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61339259/how-to-dynamically-import-svg-and-render-it-inline)

Which works great however when I build (npm run build) the svgs are not found

Any idea why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using `Webpack`, you can use [require.context](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/#requirecontext):

```
const svgDir = require.context('../../assets/svg/');
```

then:

```
<img src={svgDir(`./${filename}.svg`)}
```

**As React Component:**

```
const svgDir = require.context("!@svgr/webpack!../../assets/svg/");

const Icon = svgDir("./Group 9.svg").default
```

then:

```
<Icon />
```

Comment: thank you your answer led me to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45754739/how-to-import-an-entire-folder-of-svg-images-or-how-to-load-them-dynamically-i

I used the second answer if anyone has the same problem and reads this

Comment: Yes, if you want to use it as react component then const svgDir = require.context("!@svgr/webpack!../../assets/svg/"); and const Icon = svgDir("./Group 9.svg").default